# CSS column issue nth child

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to create 3 columns of text inputs.  Initially, this was working fine, but when you add another element above, the formatting breaks.

Please note that i have no control over the html as it's generated by a CMS.

The elements that i want in my 3 columns have a class name of 'div_short-text'.

You can see from the screenshots below what happens when i introduce a new element.  I know this issue is because i'm using nth child on the list items but not sure how to fix.

I want every 3rd instance of div_short-text to have a right  margin of zero.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83oa2uk6/)
[image]

```css
fieldset {
  background-color: #ececec;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

ol,
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none
}

.short-text,
.long-text {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.div_short-text {
  width: 31%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 24px;
}

li li:nth-child(3n+0) .div_short-text {
  margin-right: 0;
}


/* Clear on the 4,7,10 etc elements */

li li:nth-child(3n + 1) .div_short-text {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb">

<head>
  <title>Medium</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="default" />
</head>

<body>
  <form action='' method='post'>
    <div>
      <ol>
        <li>
          <fieldset>
            <legend><span>3 Col</span></legend>
            <ol>
              <li>
                <div class='field_text div_short-text'>
                  <input type="text" value="First name" maxlength='255' class="short-text" />
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class='field_text div_short-text'>
                  <input type="text" value="Middle name" maxlength='255' class="short-text" />
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class='field_text div_short-text'>
                  <input type="text" value="Last name" maxlength='255' class="short-text" />
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class='div_short-text'>
                  <input type="text" value="First name" maxlength='255' class="short-text" />
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class='div_short-text'>
                  <input type="text" value="Middle name" maxlength='255' class="short-text" />
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class='div_short-text'>
                  <input type="text" value="Last name" maxlength='255' class="short-text" />
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class='div_short-text'>
                  <input type="text" value="First name" maxlength='255' class="short-text" />
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div id='EXAMPLEINPUTS_FIELD79_OUTERDIV' class='div_short-text'>
                  <input type="text" value="Middle name" maxlength='255' class="short-text" />
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div id='EXAMPLEINPUTS_FIELD33_OUTERDIV' class='div_short-text'>
                  <input type="text" value="Last name" maxlength='255' class="short-text" />
                </div>
              </li>
            </ol>
          </fieldset>
        </li>



        <li>
          <fieldset>
            <legend><span>3 Col</span></legend>
            <ol>
              <li>
                <div class='field_text div_long-text'>
                  <input type="text" value="Loooooooooooooooooooong" maxlength='255' class="long-text" />
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class='field_text div_short-text'>
                  <input type="text" value="First name" maxlength='255' class="short-text" />
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class='field_text div_short-text'>
                  <input type="text" value="Middle name" maxlength='255' class="short-text" />
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class='field_text div_short-text'>
                  <input type="text" value="Last name" maxlength='255' class="short-text" />
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class='div_short-text'>
                  <input type="text" value="First name" maxlength='255' class="short-text" />
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class='div_short-text'>
                  <input type="text" value="Middle name" maxlength='255' class="short-text" />
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class='div_short-text'>
                  <input type="text" value="Last name" maxlength='255' class="short-text" />
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class='div_short-text'>
                  <input type="text" value="First name" maxlength='255' class="short-text" />
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class='div_short-text'>
                  <input type="text" value="Middle name" maxlength='255' class="short-text" />
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class='div_short-text'>
                  <input type="text" value="Last name" maxlength='255' class="short-text" />
                </div>
              </li>
            </ol>
          </fieldset>
        </li>
      </ol>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: it's time to change from float to better techniques like inline-block, flexbox or grid

Comment: ..or just use proper rows? Is there some reason you can't have three inputs in one div...especially as they are related. Your HTML structure isn't really logical to me.

Comment: I can't edit the HTML, it generated by a CMS

Comment: what kind of CMS adds `input` inside `div` inside `li` ?

Comment: Not sure why it orders the html that way, but it produces valid code.